# How to change material on second position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, renderer

I want to change material on position 2 , when i change material in my code it get changed on position 0 not on position 1.

I don't know how i can change material on position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noyKV.png) .. This is code that changes material on position [0]

```
 public Material[] materials;
public Renderer rend;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rend= GetComponent<Renderer>();   
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
 rend.material = materials[1];  
}
```

I want to change material on this picture with name New Material 2 
To material which i define in code.

[image]

Thank you community very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes on index 0 and not index 1 because you are using rend.material instead of rend.materials

```
public class MaterialChanger : MonoBehaviour {

public Material[] Materials;
public MeshRenderer MeshRenderer;

void Start() {
    MeshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();        
}

void Update() {
    int requredMaterialIndex = 1; //this is just test value
    MeshRenderer.materials[1] = Materials[requredMaterialIndex];   
}
```

And I suggest you to always use Meshrenderer instead of Renderer just for efficiency